# How to read live streaming data

Tags: javascript, html

I wants to read live streaming data using Javascript or HTML5.
Is it possible in Javascript or HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebSockets for that. But live video and audio is not supported in HTML5 yet.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript with HTML5. It's called the [EventSource](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) API. It's still a draft, but already supported by modern browsers.