# Reading an infinite data stream

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, python, node.js

I have a server that connects via tls and continuously outputs data in this format (when accessed through the terminal)

```
<edge event="add" from="125" to="130" timestamp="1372150050.47129" type="0" establishReasons="33" estalishedAndActive="true" delay="0.00916483299806714" jitter="0.000257230664525802" dropRate="1.27776449074903e-56" linkQuality="0" establishedFor="57146.99354947" establishRate="2.85065004752693">
<bandwidth rx="55.9164926573162" tx="57.7368275141321"/>
<sourceRedNets>
    <net address="10.0.125.0/24"/>
</sourceRedNets>
<destRedNets>
    <net address="10.0.130.0/24"/>
</destRedNets>
<peerPath>
    <peer id="130"/>
    <peer id="35"/>
    <peer id="105"/>
    <peer id="50"/>
    <peer id="70"/>
</peerPath>
```

I want to access this stream and push parts of this data (like the "edge event='add' from=....") to my browser and use it in JavaScript. How can I do this? I'm not able to figure out a way.
Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using XPath?

Comment: I can use XPath after a line of the stream has been read. I'm not able to figure out a way to read the data and push it onto JS in the first place.

Comment: related, [How to read live streaming data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064448/how-to-read-live-streaming-data?rq=1)  (with [tag:html5] and [tag:javascript])

Comment: Yep, you need to add more info about how the data is stored. Or export this data into a server and have it served in XML format. Or use websockets to get the information in parts

Comment: The data comes in this XML format whenever I access the server. The problem is that the server doesn't support a wss connection currently.  It responds on https by giving this endless XML data stream. What I want to know is if I can capture this data stream without making any changes to the server itself. Like have node.js serve as a bridge that accepts https data stream and pushes the same in wss or ws using socket.io if its not possible to capture the stream directly.  I don't know if this can work that's why I'm asking here if anyone has been able to capture an infinite https data stream.:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the ways to display 'chunked' responses as soon as they come into AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103927/what-are-the-ways-to-display-chunked-responses-as-soon-as-they-come-into-angul)